# Boyd & Vandenberghe, 9.2 — how was this derived?

Tags: convex-optimization

I'm studying convex optimization and saw the solution to the question. However I can't understand how they ended up in the last equation which I've highlighted in yellow. I have tried putting $x_1$ and $x_2$ in but can't get the last one. Could anybody help?

---

[image]

Comment: When you include text from a book it is considered good form to give a reference.

Comment: Use the fact that $\|y\|_2^2 = y^T y$ and expand the norm squared term.

Comment: @CherryHillSt. 9.2 what?

Comment: [Listed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33414/339790)